# How to reuse the same layout screen without creating a new widget tree branch

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am developing Flutter Web Application.

The object is to reuse the same layout screen widget(Drawer, AppBar) for most of route screen.

I have tried create a new Scaffold class and add body widget to each screen.

The problem is every time I navigate to a new screen. There is a new (MyScaffold) created on the widget tree. So it is not good for performance.

I also tried to use nested router, the problem is nested router is not supported by url that I can not navigate to the screen by typing the URL.

Is there any other proper way to deal with this problem.

Thanks

Add the code example :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(AppWidget());

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/second');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I will try to explain the question better.

As you can see ***First Screen*** and ***Second Screen*** has Exactly same structure of widget tree. But every time flutter is remove the Screen Widget and create a new one.

I also tried to change the code to create a new ***MyScaffold*** and reuse the same Widget class :

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyScallfold(
              bodyWidget: FirstScreen(),
            ),
        '/second': (context) => MyScallfold(
              bodyWidget: SecondScreen(),
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/second');
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 2!'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 1!'),
    );
  }
}

class MyScallfold extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget bodyWidget;
  MyScallfold({this.bodyWidget});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebAppTest'),
      ),
      body: bodyWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

Bus I noticed every time I use the navigation, all the widget of the tree is rebuilt (The renderObject #id is changed)

So is it possible to reuse the same RenderObject (AppBar, RichText) in flutter to optimise the performance ?

Comment: Are you using `Navigator.of(context).push(newRoute)`? If so, try to use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(newRoute)`.

Comment: Otherwise, it would be really helpful if you extend your question with the relevant code. That would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @josxha Thanks for your helping, I am adding the code example and try to explain my question bettre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no, not yet anyway. Currently when you use Navigator it refreshes the page and rebuilds the full view.

The most efficient way on Flutter web currently would be to use a [TabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) with a [TabBarView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) in a Stateful widget with [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html).

It only loads what Widget is on screen, but doesn't require the page to reload to view other pages. Your example would look like this (I have added animation to transition to the next page, but you can remove it):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TabController tabController;

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int activeTab = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          activeTab = tabController.index;
        });
      });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebAppTest'),
      ),
      body: Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstScreen(), //Index 0
            SecondScreen(), //Index 1
            ThirdScreen(), //Index 2
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(2);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 3!'),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(0);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 1!'),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        tabController.animateTo(1);
      },
      child: Text('To Screen 2!'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The TabView maybe the better solution for partly reloaded screen in Flutter. I was thinking of Navigator because I need the Url routing in Flutter Web for the page. So the alternative solution maybe pass the TabViewController index as a _parameter_ of router and navigate to the exact page with navigator.

Comment: Yeah, that maybe the solution, and should work fine. You could also map the Url with words to an index. /page1 == 0, /page2 == 1