# Avoid widget being re-built on navigator.push in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Exist a way to avoid that the "same" widget is rebuilt when we push a page using the navigator?

Example: avoid that MyFancyWidget() is rebuilt when we push from navigator from page 1 to page 2?

```dart
//page 1
return Scaffold(
  body: Row([
    MyFancyWidget(),
    /*Remaining part of the first page*/
  ])
);

//page 2
return Scaffold(
  body: Row([
    MyFancyWidget(),
    /*Remaining part of the second page*/
  ])
);
```

Use case:

I have faced a problem while building a sidebar in flutter web.
Since navigation inside my application is a particular issue, I need to use navigator.pushNamed every time I click on a link to a page in the sidebar. This choice was done because I need that my web-site open that specific page if the user click the reload button or load the previous one when he/she tries to navigate using the "back button" of the browser.
However using pushNamed raise an issue with the sidebar: every time the user clicks on a link the whole widget is obviously rebuilt with the rest of the page since the sidebar is part of the actual page.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change pages it will re-build the widget on Flutter Web. You can use a [TabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html) which will allow you to navigate without "reloading" the entire page.

[Read this Question to see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638403/how-to-reuse-the-same-layout-screen-without-creating-a-new-widget-tree-branch/62654170#62654170)

Comment: I already explored this solution. However, as I pointed out in the post, I need something that actually changes the URL of my page. Like this, if a user reloads the page or uses browser navigation buttons (not the one in my app), he/she can restart from where he/she left. Tab controller is awesome when you have to deal with internal navigation. However, it generates problems when the user interacts with the browser's control. I also tried to solve the issue by using internal navigation with multiple navigators. However, they don't update the URL so they don't solve the issue